# Overload class type definition in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to overload a class definition in TypeScript such that when that class is instantiated *with* a value passed to the constructor, a certain property is typed by the provided type variable(say `number`). When the class is instantiated *without* a value passed to the constructor, the same property is typed as: the provided type variable *or* undefined (ie `number | undefined`).

An example:

```
const car1 = new Car<number>(1);
car1.maxSpeed                 // maxSpeed is of type number

const car2 = new Car<number>();
car1.maxSpeed                 // maxSpeed is of type number | undefined
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly *describe* and *declare* a class constructor that works this way:

```
interface CarConstructor {
    new <T>(): Car<T | undefined>;
    new <T>(maxSpeed: T): Car<T>;
}
interface Car<T> {
    maxSpeed: T
}

declare const Car: CarConstructor;

const car1 = new Car<number>(1);
car1.maxSpeed // maxSpeed is of type number

const car2 = new Car<number>();
car2.maxSpeed // maxSpeed is of type number | undefined
```

A `CarConstructor` has two construct signatures, overloaded in the way you're talking about.

---

The problem is *implementing* such `CarConstructor`.  TypeScript doesn't let you put type parameters on `class` constructors, since currently the compiler gets any generic class type parameters from the class declaration itself and not from the constructors:

```
class BadCar<T> {
    maxSpeed: T;
    constructor<T>(): Car<T | undefined>; // error! no type params
    constructor<T>(maxSpeed: T): Car<T>; // error! no type params
    constructor(maxSpeed?: T) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed; // error! can't tell this is valid
    }
}
```

Right now all you can do is make a class that is "close enough" and then annotate or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) that it is a `CarConstructor`:

```
const Car: CarConstructor = class <T> {
    maxSpeed: T;
    constructor(maxSpeed?: T) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed as T; // <-- assume undefined is in T 
    }
}
```

This works but it cumbersome and probably becomes more cumbersome the more functionality exists in `Car` (you'll find yourself making redundant property/method definitions all over the place).

---

There is an existing GitHub issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#35387](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35387), asking for it to be easier to directly implement classes with overloaded constructors of this sort.  If you really need this you might want to go to that issue and give it a  and describe why your use case is compelling.

---

Of course, the *easiest* thing to do is not to fight against TypeScript and use a different solution, like a factory function:

```
class DumbCar<T> {
    constructor(public maxSpeed: T) { }
}

function newCar<T>(x: T): Car<T>;
function newCar<T>(): Car<T | undefined>;
function newCar<T>(x?: T): Car<T | undefined> | Car<T> {
    return new DumbCar(x);
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Hz9QaRJQABbrd7JP5tI2xxYu7Bu7CehrAADklB2EAwGB2ZY26yQADcQBgyLCi6RhZSpyQlfMFa8Ch3NNHiRbKjcchquYXSJG0qbRkvQ1mjfm0spd7ZS+WjTc7yANrJa0tpABaN9IR9QHrIJnQ1l-nIYA0iQNMkBnCCF3qdUNhQI49WEYNj0zbBFBgbhelHeBlhzWVLzwCCwPlBJaAMPgyHYW4JUUFwo06QVSPIyhKJA+waJtWI7WZGErCY4AKKo9j6SUFxz18aNtD0f8HQsCFEPA3BKG4bA2I6eC+k0WjhgyaDzXqJobk5e5QWOQYdLOJoK0+OY6zvAdAT2A5TJoPSlwM7BrjaYyAhc7BrXZN47zsvC1gBbYnJBR5BGk+0YThIA)

Answer (score 0):

In general not possible, if you try to annotate a constructor you get:

> Type annotation cannot appear on a constructor declaration. ts(1093)

In that case you should probably just define a factory function instead.

---

If the type is provided explicitly you can just specify it as such:

```
class Car<T>
{
    maxSpeed: T;
    // ...

    constructor();
    constructor(maxSpeed: T);
    constructor(maxSpeed?: any)
    {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}

const car1 = new Car<number | undefined>();
const car2 = new Car<number>(1);
```

Note that this requires the [strict null checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) compiler option.